# Review captcha error after removing recaptcha from the form

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, captcha

The recaptcha was using 1.0 which is disabled now by google.

The form.phtml in `default/default/template/review` had the following code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/recaptchalib.php');
```

&

```
<?php echo recaptcha_get_html("some-key-was-here", null, true); ?>
```

I decided to just try and remove it instead of upgrading it.

I removed the two lines of code above and checked to see if the form was back to "stock" using an original file in diffcehcker, it was.

I'm still getting an **Invalid captcha entered. Please try again.** error when submitting the form though. I did not develop this website. Any ideas on why it would still be trying to validate the captcha after being removed? Where else should I be looking?

I have tried flushing the cache.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like there may be a JavaScript file still included on the page that is checking for a valid CAPTCHA entry. Have you double checked what scripts are being added to the page using the browser console?

Comment: Also, rather than removing that code, have you tried just disabling the reCAPTCHA on the review form from the Admin? `Configuration > Sales > Google API > Google reCAPTCHA > Enabled Routes > Product Review Form`

Comment: @MagentoAaron That was my thought as well but I can't find any validation in any of the scripts being loaded on the page and it's not on in the form.phtml file itsel. I also don't have the Google reCAPTCHA option in Configuration > Sales > Google API.

Comment: Ah, looks like what I am referring to is a 3rd party extension that I've installed on all of my instances.